# iOS 8 UITextField with leftView is graphically Glitched

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

after iOS8 release the controller which shows me an account information is graphically glitched. I would post an image but i can't because I'm new here.

[image]

The glitch is that the text of the `UItextField` is overlayed to its `leftView`
But if I use the menu to change controller and then return to It, i found it correct.
The UITextField is created in the xib file.
Is modified on `viewDidLoad` method like:

```
   NVTextFieldHeader *nameFieldHeader = [NVTextFieldHeader textFieldHeaderWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"NAME_LABEL", nil)];
self.nameField.leftView = nameFieldHeader;

// Title field header
self.nameField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.nameField.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[self.nameField.layer setBorderColor: [[NVGlobals border4MEColor] CGColor]];
```

and then, on the `viewDidLoad` method i set the text on UItextField like:

```
 [self.emailField setText:self.currentUser.email];
```